# How to download large xml file without timeout exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timeout, webrequest

As you can see my codes I want to download a xml file with webrequest. I set time out to max. value. But I always get time out exception. Do you have any suggestion?

```
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("*******");
    webRequest.Timeout = 999999999;
    WebResponse myWebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: How large is the file?

Comment: You waited 277 hours? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=999999999+milliseconds+in+seconds&oq=999999999+milliseconds+in+seconds&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0.4856j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=164f700b72220e0d&q=999999999+milliseconds+in+hours

Comment: @DGibbs I can't know because I couldn't download it with any browser also.

Comment: @SpaceBison, no it throws after a couple minutes.

Comment: @cagin can you provide the link?

Comment: @cagin I wonder if the timeout is on a different part of the process then.

Comment: @DGibbs I can't share because its my customer private.

Comment: Ask the other end (where you are downloading the XML file) what is their timeout or maximum request length. Even if you set your timeout to maximum number if their timeout is let's say 2 minutes or their max request length is only 1MB.

Comment: There is a good chance that the web server configuration is overriding your request for a longer timeout. Check the configuration of the web server.

Comment: It has to be something with the server's end